# How to find the absence of elements within the time span set and without modifying the Implicit Time out of the driver in Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My Query is to find the absence of dynamic elements(more spinners) in the page.

For solving this We should use driver.findElements(By by) method which will indirectly wait until the driver's implicit wait time when the elements are not found.

My driver's implicit timeout is 15 secs.

Though reducing the implicit time out of the driver is useful to solve, 
**Is there any replacements for driver.findElements method in Selenium Webdriver?**

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can `WebDriverWait` for same. It will wait as per the time you have pass in it

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

OR

```
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

For more details refer below link:-

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

You can do something like below ...

Try to put some wait from first place

The code is in java but it is very similar/near to C#, take a reference from it

You can check everytime that your element is present or not in your HTML DOM to prevent from error/failer of script. like below:-

```
  if (driver.findElements(By."YOUR Locator")).size() != 0) {  
            YOUR FIRST Working code  
            System.out.println("element exists");     
        }  
  else{
           System.out.println("element is not exists");        
      }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the solution.
But, My problem is to find the absence of dynamic elements(more spinners) in the page. So Is there any replacements for driver.findElements method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi,

As I said already when we use findElements method it will take at the maximum of Implicit time out of the driver(i.e 15 secs) when the elements are not found. Hence Can we find the elements explicitly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below mentioned method to wait for an element without modifying implicit time

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "<URL>";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
        return d.FindElement(By.Id("<ELEMENTID>"));
    });
```

Use id of the element instead of `<ELEMENTID>` and url for `"<URL>"`